# Determine all pairs (k, n) such that there exists a k-regular graph on n vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I know that "a graph G is called k-regular if all its vertices have degree exactly k"

But I don't know to proceed towards the solution.

Question- Determine all pairs (k, n) such that there exists a k-regular graph on n vertices

Comment: For which values of $k$ and $n$ do you know the answer? For example, do you know for which values of $n$ there is a $0$-regular graph? What about $1$-regular graphs?

Comment: @bof I think 0 regular graphs can exist on any value of n and 1 regular graphs would be true for even values of n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Given an $n$, the value of $nk$ is even.